# How to select group of data and show one by one?

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2012, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table called `leads` and it has one column `company`. Each company puts up several rows (or leads) in this table. So the problem is that I use a simple `SELECT * FROM Leads` and display the output but some of the companies are pissed off that preference is given to one company over another but I cannot tell them it’s because they entered the lead first. So instead I’m looking for a solution where exactly 1 lead of each company is output and then when it exhausts showing 1 lead of each company the next set of 1-lead only appears.

So for example consider this as input table

```
Lead ID    Company
   1         ABC
   2         ABC
   3         ABC
   4         BCD
   5         CDE
   6         EFG
   7         EFG
   8         CDE
   9         ABC
  10         BCD
  11         ABC
```

Then I need something like

```
Lead ID    Company
   1         ABC
   4         BCD
   5         CDE
   6         EFG
   2         ABC
  10         BCD
   7         EFG
   3         ABC
   8         CDE
   9         ABC
  11         ABC
```

So here exactly 1 lead of each company appears and then the next company’s lead appears. When a particular companies leads are exhausted the remaining only appear. This is why in the last 2 results ABC appears twice as no other companies have unlisted leads.

Comment: What is the DB/version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the closest you can get:

```
select *
from Tab
order by 
   row_number() over (partition by Company order by LeadID)
```

The result will be ordered kind of randomly, you might add `LeadID` to the `ORDER BY`, see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd9da/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
;With Data As (
    Select
        *,
        Rank() Over (Partition By Company Order By LeadID) Rnk
    From LeadTableName
)
Select * From Data
Order By Rnk, Company
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this. @dnoeth’s answer worked thou